# Guy Ropes and Wildlife

Tags: camping, animals

A few years ago camping in Dorset, England we had an issue with the wonderfully cute local wildlife nibbling away at our guy ropes. At the time, we didn't have a replacement. So with a guy rope loosely held together by the last few fibres my other half decided to put chilli powder on every guy rope at rabbit height.

Whilst this worked and we didn't seem to have another nibble-fest for the rest of the week, and I know guy ropes are not the most expensive item to purchase but we're pretty sure our tasty tent would have needed a new 8-10 of them if we hadn't managed to prevent the rabbits eating them.

I was wondering if anyone had any alternatives to keeping rabbits and other nibbling animals off our guy ropes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use to pitch my ten in such a way that I can use the surrounding vegetation as anchors, or build small metal screens to put around the ground spike and line.

Comment: I've used a pitch break before (imagine a knee height but otherwise pointless fence) but that isn't always an option. As for metal screens that isn't really something I'd want to lug about even if I'm staying put in the same spot for a week, home making them could leave rough edges and I envision issues on a public campsite. I suppose you could have plastic ones. Could you can recommend where to buy some?

Comment: @Aravona I would not know where to buy them since I made mine myself. I just cut some aluminum and hammered into shape, they stack snugly together. I only take them when I have some extra room and weight is not an issue.